# Mongodb - Aggregation over multiple collections specific result format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to create an aggregation using information from multiple collections and arrange them in a specific result format. Here we have three collections (parent, task, slots; the model of these cannot be changed anymore). Each parent can have many tasks, which consist of different slots (see the simplified sample data below)

**Slot collection**

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499cad'),
        name: 'Test 1',
        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:00:00.000+00:00'),
        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:15:00.000+00:00'),
        parentId: 1,
        taskId: 1
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3478cad'),
        name: 'Test 2',
        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:15:00.000+00:00'),
        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09::30.000+00:00'),
        parentId: 1,
        taskId: 1
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499bcd'),
        name: 'Test 3',
        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T11:00:00.000+00:00'),
        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T11:15:00.000+00:00'),
        parentId: 1,
        taskId: 2
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499efg'),
        name: 'Test 4',
        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:00:00.000+00:00'),
        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:15:00.000+00:00'),
        parentId: 2,
        taskId: 3
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db349967e'),
        name: 'Test 5',
        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:15:00.000+00:00'),
        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:30:00.000+00:00'),
        parentId: 2,
        taskId: 3
    },
]
```

**Task collection**

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499c87'),
        name: 'Task 1',
        taskId: 1,
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499b6b'),
        name: 'Task 2',
        taskId: 2,
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db3499b19'),
        name: 'Task 3',
        taskId: 3,
    }
]
```

**Parent collection**

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db34995a6'),
        name: 'Parent 1',
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6015720974cff84db349962f'),
        name: 'Parent 2',
        parentId: 2
    }
]
```

The result should have the following format:

```
[
    {
        parentName: 'Parent 1',
        tasks: [
            {
                taskName: 'Task 1',
                slots: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Test 1',
                        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:00:00.000+00:00'),
                        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:15:00.000+00:00'),
                    },
                                        { 
                        name: 'Test 2',
                        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09:15:00.000+00:00'),
                        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T09::30.000+00:00'),
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                taskName: 'Task 2',
                slots: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Test 3',
                        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T11:00:00.000+00:00'),
                        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T11:15:00.000+00:00'),
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        parentName: 'Parent 2',
        tasks: [
            {
                taskName: 'Task 3',
                slots: [
                    { 
                        name: 'Test 4',
                        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:00:00.000+00:00'),
                        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:15:00.000+00:00'),
                    },
                    { 
                        name: 'Test 5',
                        start: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:15:00.000+00:00'),
                        end: ISO-Date('2021-07-13T13:30:00.000+00:00'),
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this result structure by given data? The lookup part is not a big deal, but I currently struggle to achieve this structure, as I'm very new to MongoDB aggregation framework. Thank you very much for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookup to join collections

- `$lookup` to join collections
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to reconstruct the array

Here is the code,

```
db.Task.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Slot",
      "localField": "taskId",
      "foreignField": "taskId",
      "as": "slots"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$slots" },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Parent",
      "localField": "slots.parentId",
      "foreignField": "parentId",
      "as": "parents"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$parents" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { pId: "$parents._id", tId: "$taskId" },
      parentName: { $first: "$parents.name" },
      taskName: { "$first": "$name" },
      slots: { $push: "$slots" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.pId",
      parentName: { $first: "$parentName" },
      tasks: {
        $push: {
          taskName: "$taskName",
          slots: "$slots"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jdTPm2DjuE2)**